# How do I properly install @angular-devkit/build-angular with Angular 13?

Tags: angular, npm, angular13, devkit, angular-devkit

I have these dev dependencies in my Angular 13 project

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.2.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.2.0",
```

When I run npm i, I get this error

```
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler@13.2.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"13.2.7" from @angular/compiler-cli@13.2.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!     dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~13.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^13.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.2.6
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~13.2.5" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (@ngtools/webpack)
```

I'm confused about how to resolve this.  Does this mean I need to upgrade my compiler cli or downgrade my devkit?  I'm also confused about how to figureout what the appropriate compatible versions are.  How do I figure out the appropriate version of devkit to satisfy the "npm i" process?

Comment: If you are stuck at this part for a long time and need to solve this asap, just add `--force` at the end of you npm i @xxx

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'm trying to get my code to build with a Git action that uses "npm i".  It is not an option to adjust the parameters of the Git action so I'm trying to figure out what the error above means.

Answer (score 0):

The @angular/compiler-cli version does not match your @angular/compiler version which is located under dependencies

Comment: Hate to be dense, but can you spell it out for me?  Does the @angular/compiler-cli version listed under devDependencies need to be 13.2.7?

Comment: Yes I think so. You have to change it in your package.json